# How are these Chinese spam iCloud Calendar/Reminders invitations sent to me?

Tags: icloud, calendar, reminders, spam

Recently, I’ve received a couple of spam event invitations in Calendar on my Mac. The most recent had only Chinese text, and recurred at 5:46am every day.

I am able to decline these by clicking on the invitations button in the toolbar (that only appears when an invitation comes in). However, ideally I’d like to not receive these spam invitations at all.

As I’ve never received a genuine invitation through Calendar, I thought I might be able to turn off the invitation feature. However, I can’t see any controls for this in Calendar preferences or the Internet Account system preferences.

Through what mechanism do these invitation arrive? If I understood what mechanism it was, I might be able to turn it off. I have two Calendar accounts enabled: iCloud, and Facebook. I can’t see anything in my e-mail, so I presume they’re not regular e-mail spam.

Since first writing this question, I’ve had a similar invitation come through in Reminders:

[image: Spam Reminder invitation]

Comment: David Sparks has [a good write-up of this problem](https://www.macsparky.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-fight-calendar-spam).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply that anyone can send an email to you. If spam rules don't block it, Apple software (with default settings) processes the invitation before you can take any action.

To prevent this automatic processing, try this.

Log in to [iCloud](http://www.icloud.com) on the web, open your calendar and go to ⚙ > Preferences (in the lower left corner). Under `Advanced` tab you’ll find an option to receive calendar invitations by e-mail instead of directly to your calendar.

[image]

Comment: Hey that looks good — I’ve given that a go, it’ll be interesting to see if any more spam ones come through and show up in my e-mail.

Comment: I know! I’ve since had a similar spam invitation appear in Reminders, which sadly does not have an equivalent settings screen on iCloud.com.

Comment: Probably you could post a new question about it.

Comment: Feels like it’s the same issue to me.

Answer (score -2):

Invitations can only come through direct email input, meaning that the inviter has your email address. How did the inviter get hold of your email? that's another issue.

Comment: “Invitations can only come through direct email input” — so they come through e-mail, but only show up in Calendar, and not at all in Mail?

Comment: If I would like to invite you into an even I would have to key-in your email address in the invitee's section. Doing so you will receive an invitation directly in your calendar where you can accept or reject. If you haven't received an email it's probably because the invitation is made through Apple's calendar. Meaning that they used a Mac to create the event.

Comment: You can report the email that keeps inviting your as a spam if you want to. Visit this link for more details:

Comment: http://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/

Comment: Gotcha — so the invitations probably go through my iCloud calendar account. That link doesn’t help me to report these, because it asks us to forward illegitimate e-mails to Apple. As I say, I don’t think I’m getting e-mails, just Calendar invitations.

Comment: Alibaba I'll bet

Comment: I never used my email from iCloud... you tell me how they got my email...